# How to allow collisions based on .srdf file

Tags: drake

Given an `.srdf` file (e.g. [pr2.srdf](https://github.com/davetcoleman/pr2_moveit_config/blob/master/config/pr2.srdf)) and a `.urdf` file (e.g. [pr2_simplified.urdf](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/pr2/models/pr2_description/urdf/pr2_simplified.urdf)), how can I tell drake to ignore collision geometries based on the `srdf` file?

Answer (score 0):

The function `load_srdf_disabled_collisions(srdf_file, plant, collision_filter_manager)` below takes a `.srdf` filename, the associated `MultibodyPlant` and the `SceneGraph`'s `CollisionFilterManager` (obtained by calling [`scene_graph.collision_filter_manager()`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#a76a5871dd4432de7e8225f334765729f)) and disable the collisions listed in the `.srdf` file.

Note that this should be called before any plant `Context` is created, otherwise, to do this for a specific `Context`, one should use [`scene_graph.collision_filter_manager(context)`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#a3d5bf882337dfed524c1da91fb96f618) instead.

It is probably worth stressing that using the raw `.urdf` file's collision geometries in all it's meshy detail will likely impact performance.  Instead, it might be a good idea to preprocess the collision geometries to the minimum amount of detail necessary for the task (see [this example of multiple levels of detail for the iiwa robot](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/urdf)).

```
def get_collision_geometries(plant, body_name):
    try:
        return plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody(plant.GetBodyByName(body_name))
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"Could not find {body_name}")
        return

def disable_collision(plant, collision_filter_manager, allowed_collision_pair):
    declaration = CollisionFilterDeclaration()
    set1 = GeometrySet()
    set2 = GeometrySet()
    set1_geometries = get_collision_geometries(plant, allowed_collision_pair[0])
    if set1_geometries is None:
        return
    set2_geometries = get_collision_geometries(plant, allowed_collision_pair[1])
    if set2_geometries is None:
        return
    set1.Add(set1_geometries)
    set2.Add(set2_geometries)
    declaration.ExcludeBetween(set1, set2)
    collision_filter_manager.Apply(declaration)

def load_srdf_disabled_collisions(srdf_file, plant, collision_filter_manager):
    tree = ET.parse(srdf_file)
    robot = tree.getroot()
    for disable_collisions in robot.iter('disable_collisions'):
        allowed_collision_pair = [disable_collisions.get('link1'), disable_collisions.get('link2')]
        disable_collision(plant, collision_filter_manager, allowed_collision_pair)
```

Possibly relevant discussions

- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/1793
- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/718